# Make subfolder act as root for the site contained in that subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to find a solution to my problem but I have not been able to find any questions/answers that address this specific issue.

I've been tasked with moving a website that was built under its own domain - www.example.com - to now reside in a subdirectory of another site - www.otherSite.com/example.

The site to be moved was built with many references to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as well as many relative URLs that start at the root. For example:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/nav.php'; ?>
```

and

```
/images/logo.jpg
```

The problem, of course, is that all of those references to the root for the site moving to the subdirectory will reference www.otherSite.com thereby breaking all of those URLs.

I'm hoping that there's a some way, possibly using .htaccess in the subdirectory, to set that subdirectory as the root for the site in that subdirectory.

Note - I am on shared hosting and do not have access to httpd.conf.

Thanks very much.

Comment: .htaccess can only solve problem of rewriting links like `/images/logo.jpg` but `include` is on server side where rewrite rule won't even come into picture.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. So basically I need to go in and modify all of the `include`s? Ok. Can you give me an example of how I would rewrite the links to add the subdirectory after the initial `/`? Thanks!

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `www.otherSite.com` host place this code in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/example/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^((?!example/).*)$ /example/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks - but that sends `www.otherSite.com` into the `example` subdirectory. I need `www.otherSite.com` to function as its own independent site and the site contained in `example` to function as its own second site. I just need to tell all of the relative URLs in the site contained in `example` that they should consider `example` as the root.

Comment: ok check updated code, rule still goes in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redirecting to the sub-folder from your cpanel?, have you check if some of the settings were stored in a database for the site if any?

Please add more codes from the site so we can understand how the codes look like.

Comment: Thanks Okwo, I will be redirecting the url to the subfolder but that will not resolve the problem of the files not being able to find the resources they need, e.g. images, stylesheets…

Comment: And while the content of the site is stored in a database, the settings were not.